# Overwriting a class attribute after returning it in method

Tags: python, numpy, class, methods

I have a class method which constructs a `numpy` array as a class attribute. I want this attribute to be set to `None` after it is returned. I'm using an attribute instead of a variable because the creating the array is done in a parallel way. These arrays can be very large so I want to avoid having it in memory twice. What would be the best way to do this?

```py
import numpy as np

class foo:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.values = None
    
    def bar(self):
        self.values = np.arange(1e9)  # Large array
        return self.values
        self.values = None  # To be set to None after returning
```

Comment: `values = self.values` `self.values = None` `return values`? Are you under the impression that `values = self.values` copies the array? Because that is not the case.

Comment: not to mention self.values = None after the return it will never be executed. return stops the execution of the function what is the point of setting to the class attribute then return in it in the same function and then setting it back to None anyway. if all you want is the big array you can just return np.arrange(1e9) no need to set it to an attribute.

Comment: @Axe319 Thanks! I missed the obvious here. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @RazvanBunga I know, I just put it like that to illustrate what I want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python does not copy objects on assignment, it only passes a reference to the same object.

`return np.arange(1e9)` will simply return a reference to the created array. Creating any new variable holding it, like `var = np.arange(1e9)`, will just assign a reference of the array to the variable.

You're welcome to [visualize](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a%20%3D%20%5B1,2,3,4%5D%0Ab%20%3D%20a%0Adel%20a&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) it if it helps.